# i get this error.... Cannot find module 'async'

Tags: node.js

I'm using NodeJS Version 11.9.0 and my OS is Windows 7 64bit. I built an App using Mongoose module, and as soon as I run my server.js I get the error `Cannot find module 'async'`

I'm sure async module already exists in my node_modules folder.
I tried to install async globally and to require it..

```
var async = require("async")

var express = require("express");

var logger = require("morgan");

//var async =  require("async");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var PORT = 3000;


// Requiring the `User` model for accessing the `users` collection

var User = require("./userModel.js");

// Initialize Express

 var app = express();

// Configure middleware

// Use morgan logger for logging requests

app.use(logger("dev"));

// Parse request body as JSON

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json());

// Make public a static folder

app.use(express.static("public"));

// Connect to the Mongo DB

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/userdb", { useNewUrlParser: true });

// Routes

// Route to post our form submission to mongoDB via mongoose

app.post("/submit", function(req, res) {

  // Create a new user using req.body

   User.create(req.body).then(function(dbUser) {

  // If saved successfully, send the the new User document to the client

      res.json(dbUser);
    }).catch(function(err) {

      // If an error occurs, send the error to the client

      res.json(err);
    });
});

// Start the server

app.listen(PORT, function() {

  console.log("App running on port " + PORT + "!");

});


$ node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'async'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:535:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\farahat\Desktop\mo\server.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
```

Comment: *"I'm sure async module already exist in my node modules folder"* What makes you sure about it? If the error says it doesn't exist then it doesn't exist.

Comment: Where and in what way do you want to use `async`?

Comment: yea, show your package.json and also check to see if async folder exists in node_modules.

Answer (score 1):

async installed globally. For that we have to create and install modules of async.

```
npm install async --save
```

this command line add files in node_modules folder.

Answer (score 0):

Rerun `npm install async`. Are you sure you want to use the `async` module or do you just want to use `async/await`? If the later, `async` is a language feature and you don't `require` any module for it.

Comment: i would like to use mongoose module but i get error said Cannot find module 'async',

Comment: don't require modules only because other modules use them. Delete your node_modules folder and install all dependencies again.